# preg match not working for me php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to create pseudo simple ex: jone/france/a3
I know it's fault but plz corrected me (code)

```
if(preg_match('~^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}+(\/)+([a-zA-Z0-9])?+(\/)+([a-zA-Z0-9])$~',$pseudo))

                      {echo "god preg";}
                    else {echo"false"}
```

Comment: Where did you get the weird quantifiers from? (Paste your regex into a testing tool to find out what they do.)

Comment: Can you explain what the pattern is trying to do? Maybe provide more example strings, and some that shouldnt be valid.

Comment: Je veux un modèle simple: example enrique / gov / e4 example piko / eyes / b9

Comment: What are the rules? Is the last part always 1 letter and 1 digit? Edit your question and add some test cases, some strings that must match and some that must not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try fixing your regular expression like this:

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\d]+[\/]+[a-zA-Z\d]+[\/]+[a-zA-Z\d]+$/', $pseudo)) {
    echo "god preg";
}
else {
    echo"false";
};
```

I tried with `$pseudo = "jone/france/a3";` Worked fine for me!

P.S: Please check regex into a testing tool to find out what they do so you can fix little stuff yourself =)

Comment: Why did you put the slashes in a character class? Why a quantifier? Why do you change regex delimiter, with `~` there're no needs to escape the slashes.